# Application logging not following the logging.pattern.level after springboot version upgrade

Tags: spring-boot

After updating the sprinboot version I started getting the following error at the beginning of the app and the logs are not following the `logging.pattern.level` from the `application.properties`

```
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,666 main ERROR Incorrect number of options on style. Expected at least 1, received 0
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,681 main WARN Class org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.ColorConverter does not extend PatternConverter.
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,683 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [clr] starting at position 4 in conversion pattern.
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,684 main ERROR Incorrect number of options on style. Expected at least 1, received 0
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,685 main WARN Class org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.ColorConverter does not extend PatternConverter.
testApp          | 2020-11-11 06:32:55,685 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [clr] starting at position 14 in conversion pattern.
```

The pattern is as follows:

```
logging.pattern.level: "%clr(%5p) %clr([%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}]){yellow}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a change in syntax in the newer versions (2.3.5+) replace `()` with `{}` as follows and see if this helps:

```
logging.pattern.level: "%clr{%5p} %clr{[%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}]}{yellow}"
```

Comment: Thanks! It started giving an another error. Will create a new question.

Comment: can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549478/application-logging-not-working-after-upgrading-springboot