# Application logging not working after upgrading springboot

Tags: spring-boot

After updating the spring boot version I started getting the following error at the beginning of the app and the logs are not following the `logging.pattern.level` from the `application.properties` and I updated them to

```
logging.pattern.level: "%clr{%5p} %clr{[%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}]}{yellow}"
```

Now I am getting an error

```
We still have an issue :
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
```

Please help me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error looks like the binder class is missing. Instead of adding the log4j based dependencies manually maybe you can add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` dependency instead and see if this helps:

Gradle:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```